# How to have the proper results using KnexJS to run a PostgreSQL query which works in a SQL script editor in a DB

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to convert a PSQL query which works in a SQL script editor to Knex.js.

I have no idea how to get my results I'm getting in DB query via Knex.js and I tried what is below.

The result of the Knex.js query is not what I want and I don't know how to get the result as explained below.

The query is as follow

```sql
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        d.id id,
        unnest(d.recipients) recipient
    from
        documents d) as result
where
    recipient = 'xxxx'
```

This query gave back a result from DB as

| id | recipient |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | xxx |
| 22 | xxx |

The recipient is always the same and the ID is the document that recipient has.
I want same result or even better with the Knex.js but I'm getting a different result and don't know what to do.

I tried to make the knex function as follow

```
findDocuments(recipientId) {
    return this.tx.raw(
      `
      SELECT
          *
        FROM
          (
          SELECT
            d.id id,
            UNNEST(d.recipients) recipient
          FROM
            documents d) as result
        WHERE
          recipient = '${recipientId}';
          `
    );
  }
```

But this in console gave a different result

```
{
   command: 'SELECT',
   rowCount: 0,
   oid: null,
   rows: [],
   fields: [
     Field {
       name: 'id',
       tableID: 19834,
       columnID: 1,
       dataTypeID: 23,
       dataTypeSize: 4,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text'
     },
     Field {
       name: 'recipient',
       tableID: 0,
       columnID: 0,
       dataTypeID: 25,
       dataTypeSize: -1,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text'
     }
   ],
   _parsers: [ [Function: parseInteger], [Function: noParse] ],
   _types: TypeOverrides {
     _types: {
       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
       arrayParser: [Object],
       builtins: [Object]
     },
     text: {},
     binary: {}
   },
   RowCtor: null,
   rowAsArray: false
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be executing the transaction, depending on whether or how you are calling the function `findDocuments()`.

Try also adding the following function to your program and executing it:

```
function runTheSQL() {
   return findDocuments()          // async execution of the query.
      .then( function(returnData) {
          console.log(returnData); // prints the query results to the console.
      });
};
runTheSQL();
```

You can also add the following clause to your knex statement (inside the `findDocuments()` function) to display the actual SQL which will be executed.

```
.on('query', function(data) {
    // outputs the SQL query you generated & runtime data bindings.
    console.log(data);
})
```